# How to fetch data where column data ends with a specific character and followed by a number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column called `REMARKS` in my table `TBL_DATA` and I have the data in table like as shown below.

```
REMARKS
--------------
Ramesh has VR2    
Ravi is VR1 member    
Rajesh had VR2    
Rakesh is VR10 employee
```

my requirement is to fetch data from table where `remarks` ends with word `VR` followed by number like `VR2, VR3,VR10,VR33`.

From the above data i want to get first and third rows data.

P.S: I should not use like operator(LIKE '%VR%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following:

```
with tbl_data(remarks) as (
    select 'Ramesh has VR2' from dual union all
    select 'Ravi is VR1 member' from dual union all
    select 'Rajesh had VR2' from dual union all
    select 'Rakesh is VR10 employee' from dual
)
select *
from tbl_data
where regexp_like(remarks, 'VR[0-9]+$')
```

which gives:

```
REMARKS
-----------------------
Ramesh has VR2
Rajesh had VR2
```

How `'VR[0-9]+$'` works:

- `VR`: self-explanatory
- `[0-9]+`: one or more occurrence of a digit
- `$`: the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular expression:

```
select t.*
from t
where regexp_like(t.remarks, 'VR[0-9]+$');
```

Answer (score 0):

another regex :

`with tbl_data(remarks) as (
    select 'Ramesh has VR2' from dual union all
    select 'Ravi is VR1 member' from dual union all
    select 'Rajesh had VR2' from dual union all
    select 'Rakesh is VR10 employee' from dual
)
select *
from tbl_data
where regexp_like(remarks, 'VR\d+$') 
;`